# Алгоритм распознания геометрических фигур

Tags: алгоритм, распознавание-образов

Задача: нужно определить, что нарисовал пользователь по заданному шаблону. Например "квадрат", "круг", "треугольник". Всего два цвета: черный и белый (без серого шума).

Порекомендуйте хорошую документацию или хороший алгоритм.

Comment: Тут недавно был вопрос по нейронным сетям и питону (поищите на форуме).

Так вот там, в одном из ответов была ссылка на распознавание.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал нейросеть. Хотя, обучение нейросети на 170 символов будет достаточно долгим процессом. Вот несколько ссылок по теме:

- [Теория нейронных сетей](http://www.aiportal.ru/articles/neural-networks/1/)
- [Простейшая нейросеть для разпознавания символов (с примером)](http://habrahabr.ru/post/171389/)

Comment: Да это лучше конечно, я думаю что эти символы можно разбить на более простые. Анализировать даже не сами рисунки , а линии при помощи которых пользователь рисовал. Думаю обучение будет попроще , чем подвергать анализу сами рисунки.

Comment: Думаю, вот этот проект будет полезен http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1591/Mouse-gestures-recognition

Comment: То,что надо, спасибо =)

Answer (score 3):

Когда передо мной было похожее задание, я использовал обход по контуру, находил периметр и площадь в пикселах, а потом сравнивал с заранее заданными буквами по [коэффициенту формы](http://www.moluch.ru/archive/28/3068/).

Comment: красивое решение!

Answer (score 2):

Пройдитесь по массиву пикселей циклом и найдите границы фигуры. Вы должны получить 4 точки, в которых, эти границы пересекаются.

- Если пиксель не равен нулю в 4 точках, то это квадрат.
- Если от одного до трех точек, то это треугольник.
- Если заполненных точек нет, то это круг.

Возможно с картинкой станет понятней.

[image]

Comment: Хорошо , но нужно что то посложнее. Я фигуры привел для примера, а сверить нужно что-то около 170 символов.

Answer (score 2):

[Преобразование Хафа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0) и [обобщённое преобразование Хафа](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0)